# Why do the MISAKA Sisters narrate everything they say?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

The MISAKA sisters from Toaru Majutsu no Index have this habit of constantly narrating everything they say in the third person, including the way they say it and actions during their speech. Moreover, the Last Order does it *twice* for every sentence.

Why do they do that? (And why doesn't anyone seem to notice?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sisters were created with suppressed emotions, as these were completely useless for the experiment. The lack of understanding their emotions and the shared memory causes them to miss any self-identity, thus they refer to themselves in the third person.

I don't know why Last Order says Misaka twice, maybe it's just because of her own *personality* because she's only 10 years old.